# OMP Single for output subroutine

Tags: fortran, openmp, gfortran

I have a code to compute a dynamic process for a duration, i.e. `it = 1, itlast`, and within this duration, I want to print certain result in every `itsprint` interval. Below is the code:

```
!$OMP PARALLEL DEFAULT (none) SHARED(w) &
!$OMP& SHARED(itlast)                       &
!$OMP& SHARED(itprint, itsprint)            &
!$OMP& PRIVATE(i, j, it)                    &
!$OMP& PRIVATE(ntprint, mtprint)
do it = 1, itlast
    !..... ALL COMPUTATIONS .....!

    !$OMP SINGLE        
    mtprint = it/itsprint
    if (itsprint*mtprint .ne. it) goto 20
        call timser(it)
20  continue
    !$OMP END SINGLE
end do
!$OMP PARALLEL END
```

And the `subroutine timser` is displayed as follow.

```
subroutine timser(it)
    use tuna_params
    implicit none

    integer :: it, k
    real :: time_s, hour

    time_s = it*delt
    hour = time_s/3600.0

    write(16,89) hour, (w(nxwtser(k),nywtser(k),2), k = 1, ntser, 1)

89  format(f10.4, 999f10.4)
end subroutine timser
```

Doing this, I allow all threads to work on computation. For every `it`, at the end of computation, only one single thread will check the `if` statement and get into `subroutine timser` for output printing. This code works just fine when using

- `gfortran (GNU Fortran (Ubuntu 4.8.4.-2ubuntu1~14.04) 4.8.4)`: `gfortran mycode.f90 -fopenmp -fbounds-check -o mycode.out`
- `ifort (Intel Compiler 16.0 Update 1)`: `ifort mycode.f90 -openmp -CB -o mycode.exe`

However, if I compile and run this code in a cluster using `gfortran (GNU Fortran (GCC) 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-50))`: `gfortran mycode.f90 -fopenmp -fbounds-check -o mycode.out`, all threads can get into `subroutine timser` and write on output file. I have no idea to debug this problem, please guide me to fix this problem. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, use tag [tag:fortran]. You can add a specific version if the question is only about that specific version (not here) or if you want to ask about differences between versions..

Comment: Probably more info will be necessary. Show the compiler version, how do you compile, how do you run it and a short full program which reproduces the behaviour (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and the output of that program.

Comment: @VladimirF Thank you for the comments, I will update the question right away.

Comment: gfortran 4.1 is really old (2008!), one of the first versions released, do not plan to use it for serious work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loks like OpenMP 2.5 was supported in gcc/gfortran since version 4.2 according to http://openmp.org/wp/openmp-compilers. Maybe the OpenMP support was not that good in gcc/gfortan 4.1.x.

The gomp history is not clear about the OpenMP status before 4.2 (https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/gomp).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have only a ssh user access to the cluster, Rocks 5.4.3 (Viper), so I cannot install anything. I have done some diggings over the internet, it appears that there is a way to install the latest gfortran in my user folder. However, different people saying different things without explaining clearly. I do not dare to spoil the cluster, is there a proper way to do this? (I'm not sure is it suitable to ask this question here, or I should ask in some other forums.)

Comment: Yes, it is very likely that you can install your own gcc/gfortran/... compiler in your home directory. Maybe the most annoying thing (besides the installation of the compiler and its dependencies) is that you'll need to set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH eveytime you want to run a binary generated with this compiler.